# RandomForest Prediction

Tags: python

I recently built a random forest algorithim to predict a y value based off of 3 independent x variables. I like the model thus far, but how do I go about predicting one set of values based off of my trained data set?

for example:

```
regressor=RandomForestRegression(n_estimators=10,random_state=0)

regressor.fit(x,y)

y_pred=regressor.predict(x)
```

my y_pred comes out as an array of prediction based off of my data

but let's say I want to estimate y given the following 3 inputs: 2.56, 294.46, 43.98

my code for that is:

```
new_predictions=regressor.predict(2.56,294.46,43.98)
```

I am getting an error of "predict () takes exactly two arguments (4 given)"

How can I predict just those three variables?

Comment: It goes in a list, `regressor.predict([2.56,294.46,43.98])`